# What is "a light-weight namespace container" created by systemd-spawn?

Tags: linux-kernel, docker, namespace, container, systemd-nspawn

`man systemd-nspawn` says

> systemd-nspawn may be used to run a command or OS in **a light-weight namespace container**.
>   In many ways it is similar to chroot(1), but more powerful since it fully virtualizes the file system
>   hierarchy, as well as the process tree, the various IPC subsystems and the host and domain
>   name.

Is a namespace container a concept only of systemd-nspawn, or of Linux kernel?

What is the relation and difference between a namespace container and a namespace?
Is a namespace container to systemd-nspawn as a namespace to Linux kernel? In other words, 
Is a namespace container  systemd-nspawn's version of namespace?

Is a docker container based on  a namespace container?

Thanks.

Comment: A possible duplicate of the last n questions asked by Tim. As you know docker containers uses name-spaces, so NO. Both docker and by the look of it systemd-nspawn use the same mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

[Containers aren’t a first-class concept](https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/containers-zones-jails-vms/), directly provided by the kernel; they are assembled using various features provided by the underlying operating system, including, on Linux, [namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html). Different container runtimes use different features, and in some cases the feature set can vary from one container to another in the same runtime.

A “namespace container” is a container constructed using namespaces. Based on your quote, one can imagine that `systemd-nspawn` uses at least mount namespaces, PID namespaces, IPC namespaces, and UTS namespaces; [its manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html) indicates that it also uses system call filters and some form of resource limitation.

Docker containers also use namespaces, along with many other features.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Is a “namespace container” created by systemd-nspaw constructed using also cgroups or somthing else besides namespaces? (2) Is a “namespace container” not a concept provided by the kernel? (3) Is a “namespace container” simply a number of namspaces, so is a concept provided by the kernel, and can be created using API of the kernel, without using systemd-nspawn? (trying to compare a “namespace container” to a docker container)

Comment: The reason I asked these questions is that I would like to know if systemd-nspawn (containers) and docker (containers)  work at different or the same level (subject to your understanding, I don't have a clear understanding yet).

Comment: Is it correct that both a systemd-nspawn container and a docker container  are above the Linux kernel level, i.e. the kernel isn't aware of both, and the two are just two different implementations of the same (or maybe different) "container" concept?

Comment: What’s so hard to understand about the fact that containers aren’t a concept the kernel knows about?

Comment: Am I correct that to users, systemd-cgls seems to deal directly with cgroups provided by kernel, while systemd-nspawn indirectly with namespaces provided by kernel. "It is hard", because I just want to make sure.

Comment: I’ve told you, multiple times, that containers aren’t a kernel-level concept. I’m not sure how else to say it, or what to do to convince you that it’s true. I don’t understand what `systemd-cgls` has to do with anything all of a sudden. “To users”, it shouldn’t matter what kernel-level concepts are used to implement a command.