# Does the Linux Kernel define a container?

Tags: linux, container

I know this is pedantic but I run `man namespaces`, I see

> A  namespace  wraps a global system resource in an abstraction that makes it appear to the processes within the namespace that they have their  own  isolated  instance  of the global resource.  Changes to the global resource are visible to other processes that are members of the namespace, but are invisible to other processes. **One use of namespaces is to implement containers.**

When it says "to implement *containers*", what do I need beyond namespace isolation to call what I'm doing a "container"? Alternatively, and more specifically, if I run `unshare` to a launch a program in a different user namespace is that a "container"?

Answer (score 1):

The kernel doesn’t define containers; see [What is "a light-weight namespace container" created by systemd-spawn?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/510906/86440). Containers as commonly understood provide both isolation (using namespaces) and resource control (using cgroups), as well as further levels of protection such as seccomp filters. They combine multiple concepts, they aren’t instances of a first-class concept provided directly by the kernel.

`unshare` deals with the namespace side of things, you’d have to add the rest (thus implementing a container runtime).

Comment: On a pedantic point of nomenclature I would suggest that these things need to be combined into a single entity before I use the term.  That is, if you manually isolate a process with namespaces I wouldn't refer to that as a container.  If those same manual steps were put into a script, I might.  The difference being there needs to be some *thing* to call a container.

Comment: Right, I don’t think that contradicts what I wrote, at least in the answer I linked to — I should have spelled it out here too: the kernel doesn’t define a container.

Answer (score 0):

## Linux Foundation

Looking for an actual definition of this on the Linux Foundation, it seems a "container" is not defined by the level of isolation, or privilege-controls -- these are *"building-blocks"* -- but instead by,

- instantiation from an image which includes the application, its dependencies, and the user-space libraries
- running on host's kernel
- subject to external resource limitations and isolation

So I guess the real question here is whether a shell script with `unshare` is an unshare.

I'm taking this from the [LinuxFoundationX's LFS151.x on edx](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:LinuxFoundationX+LFS151.x+2T2020/courseware/c1aa3ca55dd84850bc5d69dcf06a1c3e/2a40209b7c6a4bd5855aa960210b9e8c/?activate_block_id=block-v1%3ALinuxFoundationX%2BLFS151.x%2B2T2020%2Btype%40sequential%2Bblock%402a40209b7c6a4bd5855aa960210b9e8c)